# How to fix datas which aren't fetched in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm learning Vue 3 and I've got an issue with data to fetch. I used the same principle as on this link ( https://vuejs.org/examples/#fetching-data ). I just changed the datas with mine from a personal API, but I end up with this error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')
    at Proxy.render (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/views/HomeView.vue?vue&type=template&id=9ea40744:32:439)
    at renderComponentRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:952:16)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5814:46)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:217:19)
    at instance.update (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5927:51)
    at setupRenderEffect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5935:5)
    at mountComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5725:5)
    at processComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5678:9)
    at patch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5166:11)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5886:9)
```

Here is my code:

```js
    <script setup>
    import logo from "@/assets/logoo.svg";
    import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

    const home = ref(null)

    const API_URL = 'https://url.monapi?locale='
    const locales = ['en', 'fr']

    const currentLocale = ref(locales[0])
    const datas = ref(null)

    watchEffect(async () => {
    const url = `${API_URL}${currentLocale.value}`
    datas.value = await (await fetch(url)).json()

    console.log(datas.value.data.attributes.text)
    })
    </script>
```

```html
    <template>
      <main class="homepage">
        <div>

          <template v-for="locale in locales" :key="locale.id">
            <input type="radio"
              :id="locale"
              :value="locale"
              name="locale"
              v-model="currentLocale">
            <label :for="locale">{{ locale }}</label>
          </template>
    
        <p>vuejs/vue@{{ currentLocale }}</p>
    
        <!-- eslint-disable-next-line no-console -->
        <p>{{ datas.data?.attributes.text }}</p>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="{ id } in datas" :key="id">
            {{ id }}
          </li>
       </ul>
```

Comment: The `datas` on your `<li>` v-for is going to cause that error because template code runs synchronously, it does not wait for data to come later, and `datas` initially is null.  You should just put a `v-if="datas"` on the `<ul>` to prevent an error like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that you're using the `watchEffect` function. `watchEffect` runs immediately when the component is created and re-runs when its dependencies change. It doesn't wait for data to be fetched before the component is rendered.

To mitigate this, you can use conditional rendering to ensure that the component doesn't try to access `datas.data?.attributes.text` until `datas` is not null.

```
<p v-if="datas && datas.data">{{ datas.data?.attributes.text }}</p>
<ul>
    <li v-for="{ id } in datas?.data" :key="id" v-if="datas && datas.data">
        {{ id }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also, you may want to handle fetch errors in your `watchEffect`:

```
watchEffect(async () => {
    const url = `${API_URL}${currentLocale.value}`
    try {
        datas.value = await (await fetch(url)).json()
        console.log(datas.value.data.attributes.text)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch data:', error)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you Aous Mohammad! It works!

However, do you think there is a better way to do it? I mean you said that I used watchEffect, but maybe a simple watch can be better?